# GCP VM access on local virtualbox

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, virtualbox, ssh-keys

I have downloaded Google clound VM to local in VMDK format and configured in local virtual box.
Now i want to know how to login into that VM. On google cloud , we can login through SSH Key setup.
but how to use those SSH Key when the same VM is running in local.

I am new to Google cloud. Please help.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you successfully spin up and run GCP VM image locally in VirtualBox and now you're looking for a way to log in.

If you use [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk) locally your SSH private key is `google_compute_engine`:

```
$ cd ~/.ssh
~/.ssh$ ls -l
total 28
-rw------- 1 username username 1823 Jul  2  2020 google_compute_engine
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username  397 Jul  2  2020 google_compute_engine.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 4884 Mar  4 08:31 google_compute_known_hosts
```

**To connect to you VM** you can use a command on Linux:

```
ssh -i PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY USERNAME@VIRTUAL_BOX_VM_IP
```

or you can configure using private SSH key file for authentication with Putty like [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#windows-putty).

Alternatively, you can add user and password to your VM instance before downloading it.

Comment: Thanks Serhii..  :)

Comment: Hi Serhii,  what would be the VIrtual box VM IP as this would be running as local now.

Comment: IP address of the VirtualBox VM depends on the configuration. Have a look on [this article](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Network_Configuration_in_VirtualBox) or [documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) to find more details.

Comment: @sumit9827 - Lookup the IP address in your DHCP server. There are tools that can scan your local network looking for open ports. Scan for port 22 (ssh).